# Diode functional naming : 'ORing' diode

Tags: diodes, naming-conventions

I heard 'ORing Diode' in a design meeting today.

After a quick google search I found this was referring to a diode functional montage.

[image]

Is this naming commonly used? Are there other names like this?

I know this question is very wide, but it is still worth asking.

Comment: Yes, it's commonly used. Note the capital R for OR, the logic function.

Comment: Another usage besides isolating DC voltage sources is to build [digital logic gates](https://www.niser.ac.in/sps/sites/default/files/basic_page/logic%20gate%20circuits.pdf).

Comment: @winny I've edited post title according to your comment.

Comment: @Seir I'm aware of the different use of diode, but I didn't knew this kind of naming 'ORing', 'ANDing?'

Comment: A related question on _ENG.SE_: [Should I use "ORing" or "OR'ing" when referring the verb of the Boolean logical operator "OR"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343653/should-i-use-oring-or-oring-when-referring-the-verb-of-the-boolean-logical) I personally use _OR-ing/AND-ing_. But I'm not aware if there is an official correct notation.

Comment: @Seir Thanks ! :)

Comment: Diodes are used to implement logic functions - especially back in the 50’s and 60’s. Whilst I missed those times and grew up with TTL logic, sometimes it was convenient to use diodes.

Comment: Thanks. I can foresee confusion when someone asks for an O-ring diode, especially in a group with mechanical engineers.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is this naming commonly used?*

It's used quite often in my opinion.

> *Is there other naming like this?*

An improvement on the diode OR circuit is a **power path controller** that replaces the diodes with low-forward-volt-drop MOSFETs. General idea: -

[image]

And, it can sometimes can be called a prioritizer: -

[image]

Images from [Primer on PowerPath Controllers, Ideal Diodes & Prioritizers](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/primer-on-powerpath-controllers-ideal-diodes-prioritizers.html#:%7E:text=A%20PowerPath%20controller%20is%20basically,latter%20is%20called%20a%20prioritizer.)

And, if you think about the OR-ing diodes, isn't that just what a bridge rectifier does: -

[image]

Image from [LT4320 data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4320fb.pdf).